# JOOQ generation from PostgreSQL procedures using ARRAY out-types

Tags: postgresql, generator, jooq

When generating java code with JOOQ(3.5.1) I'm getting Null pointer exception, if procedure has an Table return type with an array typed field.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(IN param1 integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(result1 integer, result2 integer[]) AS
  ....
```

Generator error:

```
Error while generating table record public.func1     
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:637)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:828)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getType(DefaultDataType.java:841)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getType(JavaGenerator.java:3220)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getType(JavaGenerator.java:3185)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getType(JavaGenerator.java:3194)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getJavaType(JavaGenerator.java:3173)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getJavaType(JavaGenerator.java:3169)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.getRowType(JavaGenerator.java:935)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateRecord(JavaGenerator.java:700)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateRecord(JavaGenerator.java:659)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateRecords(JavaGenerator.java:648)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:309)
at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:247)
at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:402)
at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:167)
at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool$main.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
```

Comment: Is the missing type of `param1` perhaps relevant to this question? I cannot get such a function into the database, but perhaps you could, and this now has side-effects on the code generator?

Comment: No. changing the last parameter type to text gets rid of this error

Comment: I mean your in parameter `IN param1`. It should probably be something like `IN param1 integer`...

Comment: I just omitted it when made a more simple case from the real function I have. I edited the question. Anyway, the function I have works properly, so there should not be a syntax error. The problem is only with Jooq Generation

Comment: Hmm, yes, I can actually reproduce this with jOOQ 3.5.x - I was trying with a snapshot version of 3.6.0 so far (where this works). I've registered https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4052. Will keep you posted

Comment: Note, 3.5.2 has been released including a fix. It was about time to ship it anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a bug in jOOQ 3.5.1](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4052) and will be fixed in jOOQ 3.6.0 and 3.5.2.